# Connected space with disconnected interior?

Tags: general-topology

Is there a topological space $X$ where: $X$ is connected, $\partial X$ is connected, but $int(X)$ is not?

Comment: It would improve your Question to make the body text as self-contained a statement of your problem as possible (supplying context such as what makes the problem interesting, and/or what approaches you've already considered, etc.).  Relying on the title alone for the statement of a problem is prone to create difficulties for your Readers.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$
\{(x,y):x^2+y^2+2x\le 0\}\cup\{(x,y):x^2+y^2-2x\le 0\}
$$
that is, the union of two circles, touching at the origin.

What's the boundary? What's the interior?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the subset of the plane shown at the top of the picture below: it’s the union of two disks that are tangent to each other. For example, it could be everything on and inside the circle $(x+1)^2+y^2=1$ and everything on and inside the circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, two disks of radius $1$ that are tangent at the origin.

The boundary is the sideways figure $8$ shown at the bottom of the picture: it is certainly connected, since there is even a path in it from any point of it to any other point of it. The interior, however, is the two open blue disks in the upper picture. That blue set is not connected, because the two open disks are disjoint non-empty open subsets whose union is the entire interior.

[image]